# Как организовать поиск по вложенным документам с неизвестный промежуточным узлом?

Tags: mongodb

Есть структура:

```
{
  "A" : {
    "B1" : {
      "C" : {
        "K1" : {
          "x" : NumberLong(12),
          "y" : NumberLong(13)
        }
      }
    },
    "B2" : {
      "C" : {
        "K1" : {
          "x" : NumberLong(35),
          "y" : NumberLong(45)
        },
        "K2" : {
          "x" : NumberLong(1),
          "y" : NumberLong(0)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Есть задача:
Выбрать все **K1**(переменная которая передается) из всех **B*n***

Пробовал сам но есть проблемы:

1. Как указать не явно **B1**, а все **B*n***
2. Как в результат category запихнуть само название ключа **B*n***

> ```
> .aggregate([
>     {$match:{
>         "A.B1.C.K1":{
>             $exists:true
>         }
>     }},
>     {$project:{
>         "result":"A.B1.C.K1",
>         "category":"B1",
>         "_id":false
>     }}
> ]);
> ```

Comment: А из коллекции по какому критерию документы должны выбираться?

Comment: Выбрать все K1 из А

Comment: Я имею ввиду из коллекции mongodb. Это же у вас один документ. По какому то критерию он выбирается или он единственный в коллекции?

Comment: Если сама выборка документов не требуется, то задача может быть легко решена уже на клиенте. Т.к. в монге, насколько знаю, нет поддержки wild для путей внутри документа (и по сути не может быть, скорей всего, потому что например массив может находится по пути), а в aggregation framework нет динамических имен (пока что).

Comment: Жаль((( Это я сильно упростил пример. На самом деле, у меня огромное дерево с кучей веток и нод. И мне всего лишь нужно найти все вхождения дочерней ноды плюс вытащить часть пути. Перебирать все накладно по ресурсам, думал может можно одним запросом вытащить только то что нужно

Comment: А можно ли искать по ключам с условием сравнения строк? Например проверить есть ли ключи в диапазоне $gte:'20:00'